# Access not Configured with PHP using Google Translate V2

Tags: php, translation, google-translate

I have **enabled billing** and have 10$ balance in my project, 
I have created Key for browser applications, with **right referrer** 
I have **generate key** , my code is given below

```
$api_key = 'My Key is Here';


$response = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key='.$api_key.'&q=hello%20world&source=en&target=de');

//decode json to array
$json = json_decode($response);

//show the json array in a readable format
echo '<pre>';

//show array
print_r($json);
```

I am getting following errors

stdClass Object
(
    [error] => stdClass Object
        (
            [errors] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [domain] => usageLimits
                            [reason] => accessNotConfigured
                            [message] => Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.
                        )

```
            )

        [code] => 403
        [message] => Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.
    )
```

)

Please would you help me to figure out,  what i have missed or did wrong that i get above error.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled translate API in developer console.
[image]